# Gmate for gedit3 (new version of Ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

Sorry for the offtop, but I am asking all who use gmate+gedit for ruby and ruby-on-rails development. Today I have upgraded Ubuntu to 11.10 and all plug-ins for gedit fall off.
Do you know how to force to work them? Or they still don't work with gedit3? Ubuntu 11.10 uses only the gedit3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gedit3 does not support gedit2 plugins, it means all plugins of gedit2 will not work in gedit3, they have to be upgraded/rewritten to work in gedit3.

For Ubuntu 11.10 you can use https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-on-rails/+archive/ppa to keep track of useful latest plugins for gedit3.

Or use plugins from https://github.com/gmate/gmate there are also additional colorschemes, snippets and lang-specs.